# Negate boolean in JPQL order by

Tags: sql, boolean, sql-order-by, jpql

I have an entity like

```
Student{
id, 
name,
active,
rank
}
```

I want to select based on active and rank, and want active students first and having rank in asc order.

In Postgres SQL I can write a query like :

```
Select * from Student order by (Not active), rank;
```

Is there any same way to write in JPQL ?

Comment: Can you not just use `active desc, rank asc`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks its working.